# Flutter deletes file from local directory after restart

Tags: flutter, dart

I copy image from gallery to app directory like this:

```
 file.copy("${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/media/foo.jpg");
```

And it works. But when i restart app, file dissappears.
So how should i save images to keep them even after app restart?

Comment: `file.copy()` returns a future, so you have to `await` it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my other code. I was trying to copy file to the same path and it didn't work properly. So, I added if check and it resolved problem.

```
if(file.path != newPath){
 await file.copy(newPath);
}
```